# Is it possible to add a user to Active Directory in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to add a user to Active Directory in an ASP.NET MVC application? I can add users in Azure but this has to be done by the Azure administrator. I would prefer users could create themselves as they do in local account signup.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-add-connected-service

Comment: Yes but this doesn't tell you how to create a user in a separate application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question `Is it possible to add a user to Active Directory in an ASP.NET MVC application?`. The answer is "**yes**", we can do it by request [microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in your ASP.NET MVC application.

If we do it by microsoft graph api(no matter you use "Delegate" or "Application" permission type), both of them need administrator (need administrator or administrator assign permission to the application). So for your requirement of `would prefer users could create themselves as they do in local account signup`, it can't be implemented.

If you just want users to register as guest user but not local user in Azure AD, this may be achievable. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow#:%7E:text=Azure%20AD%20is%20the%20default,support%20Google%20and%20Facebook%20accounts.).